# How to copy all files from a source to destination under a folder by matching folder names using node?

Tags: node.js, npm, copy, frontend, package.json

I am doing something similar to below but its not working

ncp src/projectname/components/content/**componentname**/clientlib/*.less

../abc/src/main/content/jcr_root/apps/projectname/components/content/**componentname**/clientlib/*.less

I need to copy all files under clientlib by matching the **componentname** in source and destination.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using Node child_process built-in module which help you to execute any external command like as ncp command.

Here is the code:

```
var myCmd = 'ncp src/projectname/components/content/componentname/clientlib/*.less ../abc/src/main/content/jcr_root/apps/projectname/components/content/componentname/clientlib/*.less';
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec(myCmd, function (err, stdOut, stdErr){if(!err){console.log('Command run successfully');} else{console.log(stdErr);}});
```